# How can you add the currently running application to the Windows Audio Mixer without playing any sound?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a music player program which creates an `IAudioSessionControl2`. This is required in order to be able to change its own custom volume mixer volume.

The issue is that the `IAudioSessionControl2` cannot be created when the application does not have an Audio Mixer instance, and in order to create an Audio Mixer instance I need to play some sounds using the `PlaySound()` function or any other audio. Windows adds the instance to an application after is has played some sound.

One solution that I could use is making a blank wave and playing that when the application is created, but that feels cumbersome, and I would need to embed the file in the application via resources.

Some applications, such as Firefox or Windows Media Player legacy, are able to do this when they are opened, even though they have not played any sound.

So, would there be a more elegant solution to add the app to the Volume Mixer without utilizing any kind of blank audio files?

Comment: You should be using [IAudioSessionManager interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessionmanager) for creating `IAudioSessionControl2`. In fact if you read [IAudioSessionControl2 interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessioncontrol2) documentation you can clearly see that there are two ways of creating `IAudioSessionControl2` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the IAudioSessionManager2 as suggested by `SilverWarior`, following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessioncontrol2) documentation I was able to create the following function which adds the application to the Volume Mixer:

```
procedure ActivateAudioSession;
var
  AEnumerator: IMMDeviceEnumerator;
  ADevice: IMMDevice;
  ASessionManager: IAudioSessionManager2;
  ASessionControl: IAudioSessionControl;
begin
  // Create the device enumerator
  CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, nil, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator, AEnumerator);

  // Get the default audio device.
  AEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, ADevice);

  // Get the audio client.
  ADevice.Activate(IID_IAudioSessionManager2, CLSCTX_ALL, nil, ASessionManager);

  // Create session
  ASessionManager.GetAudioSessionControl(nil, 0, ASessionControl);
end;
```

If using a console application, `CoInitialize()` and `CoUnInitialize()` will need to be executed at the app start and close. This is not required for VCL applications, as those calls are made automatically.

Comment: DO NOT call `Co(Un)Initialize()` inside your function like this. You should be calling those functions in your app's startup/shutdown code instead. And if you are using VCL then they are already called for you. Imagine what happens if you were to call your function and COM hadn't been initialized yet? You would be ripping COM out from behind the Session Manager's back before your function released the interfaces it had obtained. If you are going to init/release COM like this, you need to release your interfaces before releasing COM itself